# Restoring pages in wordpress

Tags: functions

during maintenance work on my page i've tried to modify "functions.php" but after I tried to save my changes whole page crashed and my "fucntions.php" went blank ! It turned out that my "Disk quota exceeded" Thankfuly I made a backup copy of "functions.php" before an edit so after removing some unnecessary photos I've restored "functions.php" and my site is live again. BUT some of the pages disappeared. For example on my lisitng page I am able to see only 11 pages but the counter shows that I should have got 61 published sites.

[image: Admin Panel - pages listing]

Is there any way to restore those pages ??

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to restore your WP database, if you have backup. If not, ask your hosting provider to do that, if you are on shared on VPS hosting, they should make full backup of your account and database every 1-2 days (even without your knowing).

Because you exceeded disk quota, maybe something else is not written to the disk, or partly, so my best recommendation is to ask your hosting provider to restore your database, maybe even better your full account, on shared and VPS systems it will be quickly. If you are on dedi server, than you probably have your backup and you know how to do that yourself.